# What is the difference between MVC and Entity Framework in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

What is the difference between MVC and Entity Framework in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3):

#### MVC

> MVC, as the name suggests, follows a pattern called
> model-view-controller. It defines the shape of an ASP.NET web
> application and the interactions between the components it contains.

The MVC pattern is nothing new and dates back to 1978, but it gained widespread popularity because of the following reasons:

• User interaction in MVC pattern follows a
natural cycle: the user takes an action, and in response, the application changes its
data model and delivers an updated view to the user. Then the cycle repeats.

• Web applications combine multiple technologies (databases, HTML,
and executable code, for example), usually split into a set of layers. The
patterns that arise from these combinations map naturally onto the concepts in the
MVC pattern.

Have a look [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/mvc) to learn more about MVC.

#### Razor

> In an ASP.NET Core MVC application, a view engine is used to render the content that has been sent to clients. The default view engine is called Razor, and it processes annotated HTML files that insert dynamic content into the output sent to the browser.

This isn't applicable to ASP.NET, Razor pages were introduced in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.

Learn about Razor pages [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/).

#### Entity Framework (Core)

> Entity Framework Core—also known as EF Core—is an object-relational mapping (ORM) package produced by Microsoft that allows .NET Core applications to store data in relational databases.

Put another way, Entity Framework Core acts as the bridge between an ASP.NET Core MVC application and a database.

Read more about EF [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/).

#### Web API

> The popularity of MVC inspired another new web property. The WEB API. Where MVC tried to take off where Web Forms left, WEB API tries to do the same for Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP).

Continue reading about [WEB API's](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis).